# Problem with WebView, gets stuck in loading

Tags: javascript, php, android, android-studio, webview

I am having a problem where my page gets stuck in a load page, it's just with that page, I thought it was because it had no javascript enabled, then added it and added a bunch of other code probably I won't need, but it was to discard.

Any idea what it would be the problem?

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Obtain the WebSettings object//
    WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();

    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
                                   }

                               });



browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        browser.clearView();
        browser.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            browser.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/databases/");
        }
        browser.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        browser.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        browser.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        browser.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
        browser.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        browser.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        browser.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        browser.setInitialScale(1);


    browser.loadUrl("https://s167-es.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=ingame&component=overview");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Loading... Wait, please...",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // evita que los enlaces se abran fuera nuestra app en el navegador de android
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

}

[image: This is how it gets stucks (always loading)]

Then in a normal browser what should happen is that it would open a new tab with the game in there, which uses javascript too just in case it's important.

[image: Here is where you click in the normal browser, which is that button I click on the emulator and then i get the loading stuck page.]

And here is the **source code view** from the previous image: (in google chrome, but my points it's maybe you find something that helps you determine if I'm lacking of some code in the webview or something.

```
<!do ctype htm l><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=de vice-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"><script type="text/javascript" src="/config/configuration.js"></script><title></title><link href="https://s3-static.geo.gfsrv.net/browsergamelobby/ogame/2.7.0/css/main.33ce9fb9.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><div class="planet"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-static.geo.gfsrv.net/browsergamelobby/ogame/2.7.0/js/main.b0b4a5d3.js"></scri pt></body></html>
```

Here is my **LOGCAT**: `2020-02-07 02:45:31.362 21035-21035/? I/me.serverOctan: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.377 21035-21035/? E/me.serverOctan: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-02-07 02:45:31.384 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-02-07 02:45:31.518 21035-21070/? D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2020-02-07 02:45:31.520 21035-21070/? W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.507 21035-21035/? W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:124): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7421 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c142,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=OGame.serverOctans
2020-02-07 02:45:31.532 21035-21070/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-02-07 02:45:31.535 21035-21070/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-02-07 02:45:31.537 21035-21070/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-02-07 02:45:31.614 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.614 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.623 21035-21035/? I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 74.0.3729.185 (code 373018518)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.626 21035-21035/? I/me.serverOctan: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-02-07 02:45:31.629 21035-21035/? I/me.serverOctan: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-02-07 02:45:31.660 21035-21035/? I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 4 ms (timestamps 5821-5825)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.673 21035-21035/? I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(50)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
2020-02-07 02:45:31.673 21035-21035/? I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "74.0.3729.185", actual native library version number "74.0.3729.185"
2020-02-07 02:45:31.678 21035-21075/? W/cr_ChildProcLH: Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.google.android.webview, sandboxed = true
2020-02-07 02:45:31.683 21035-21075/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/Context;->bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handler;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.688 21035-21035/? I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
2020-02-07 02:45:31.819 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.819 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->logEvent(Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.819 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionStarted(I)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.820 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(II)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.820 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.820 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextSelection;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.820 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.820 21035-21035/? W/me.serverOctan: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(IIILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.851 21035-21111/? D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe1a3fd20, tid 21111
2020-02-07 02:45:31.858 21035-21111/? D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
2020-02-07 02:45:31.864 21035-21103/? W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
2020-02-07 02:45:31.887 21035-21111/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe1a1baa0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
2020-02-07 02:45:31.890 21035-21111/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1a1baa0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe1a0fec0)
2020-02-07 02:45:31.893 21035-21111/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-02-07 02:45:31.893 21035-21111/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-02-07 02:45:31.976 21035-21068/? D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xde52daa0, tid 21068
2020-02-07 02:45:31.977 21035-21068/? D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
2020-02-07 02:45:31.977 21035-21068/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-02-07 02:45:31.993 21035-21111/? I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
2020-02-07 02:45:31.996 21035-21111/? W/cr_MediaCodecUtil: HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
2020-02-07 02:45:32.011 21035-21068/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xebb10080: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
2020-02-07 02:45:32.020 21035-21068/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebb10080: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xca674190)
2020-02-07 02:45:32.036 21035-21068/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-02-07 02:45:32.036 21035-21068/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-02-07 02:45:32.036 21035-21111/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe1a1ca60: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2020-02-07 02:45:32.038 21035-21111/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1a1ca60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe1a0fec0)
2020-02-07 02:45:32.050 21035-21111/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-07 02:45:32.050 21035-21111/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-07 02:45:32.079 21035-21068/? W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2020-02-07 02:45:32.083 21035-21068/? D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-02-07 02:45:32.084 21035-21068/? D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xca9745b0, tid 21068
2020-02-07 02:45:32.085 21035-21068/? D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
2020-02-07 02:45:32.086 21035-21068/? D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
2020-02-07 02:45:32.086 21035-21068/? D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff740000 size 0x2000
2020-02-07 02:45:32.102 21035-21068/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebb10080: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xca674190)
2020-02-07 02:45:32.156 21035-21111/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-07 02:45:32.157 21035-21111/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-07 02:45:32.160 21035-21068/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebb10080: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xca674190)
2020-02-07 02:45:32.198 21035-21068/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebb10080: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xca674190)
2020-02-07 02:45:32.414 21035-21090/OGame.serverOctans D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-02-07 02:45:34.074 21035-21068/OGame.serverOctans E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-07 02:45:34.074 21035-21068/OGame.serverOctans E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-07 02:45:34.643 21035-21111/OGame.serverOctans E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-07 02:45:34.646 21035-21111/OGame.serverOctans I/chatty: uid=10142(OGame.serverOctans) Chrome_InProcGp identical 2 lines
2020-02-07 02:45:34.646 21035-21111/OGame.serverOctans E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
2020-02-07 02:45:37.285 21035-21091/OGame.serverOctans W/chromium: [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(3232)] Received HEADERS for invalid stream 23`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is related to the content on that URL being completely dynamical created (as you can see in the HTML source) with JavaScript and you have not enabled JavaScript in your `WebSettings`.

There are a few other things happening that is making your code dense to read.

You have this line:

```
WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
```

But then you do this:

```
browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Which could have been written as:

```
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

As to the issue, I believe the following line may fix the loading:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Personally, I would also include:

```
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your recommendations. 
Regarding the issue, it's still having the same problem. Yes, I believe It's like you said, if you meant that it redirects you through some URLS before "hitting the right one". I think the problem is the Lobby, because you cannot directly log in in the game as it used to be.

The game makes you Log In, then you are redirected to the lobby even if you were already logged in the game, and then you need to press PLAY or "Jugar" to go the link I INITIALLY wanted to go to.

Comment: I just realized that It's stuck in this link: https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/es_ES/loading

You can actually see in the link that It's just like a loop WHILE it really loads the real web it has to go to. But the problem then it's that it's not redirecting properly after loading, or actually doesn't really loads the website, so it cannot redirect, maybe. I think it has to be one of those two options.